# Updating an ObservableCollection based on database table changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

In a WPF application, I have an ObservableCollection that is populated and updated by a stored procedure call to SQL Server(querying a table). Then, the UI objects are updated using values from this ObservableCollection.

How can I implement this to be automatic in that the stored procedure will be called when a new row is added to the underlying database table in SQL Server? Then, the ObservableCollection would be updated and the datagrid will display the current records.

Maybe a separate thread running for every certain time? But I really only need to run it when there is an insert on the table.

Comment: I recommend that you look into Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm using entity framework, could you be more specific?

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss read the question, you want to change value in program when SQL DB value changes

Comment: i want the datagrid to display the most current records, so whenever a new row is added to the underlying database table, I want the ObservableCollection to be updated

Comment: I believe the only reasonable way of doing this would be using a timer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409558/c-sharp-timer-run-every-5th-minute